# expectation value of two unioned sets

Tags: probability, stochastic-processes

## Problem

We have two sets $A, B \subseteq \{1,...,n\}$, that are generated with two independent random experients. Every element $x\in \{1,...,n\}$  gets allocated to $A$ with probability $p_A$ and to $B$ with probability $p_B$.

The question is: What is the expected value of the cardinality of the set $A\cup B$

---

## My guess:

$E[|A\cup B|]=E[|A|+|B|-|A\cap B|]=E[|A|]+E[|B|]-E[|A\cap B|]$

#### expected value of $|A|$ and $|B|$:

$E[|A|]= (p_A)^0*(1-p_A)^n*0 + (p_A)^1*(1-p_A)^{n-1}*1+\ldots + (p_A)^n*(1-p_A)^0*n= \sum_{i=0}^{n} (p_A)^i*(1-p_A)^{n-i}*i$

$E[|B|]= \sum_{i=0}^{n} (p_B)^i*(1-p_B)^{n-i}*i$

#### the expected value of $|A\cap B|$:

The probability that an element $x$ is in $A\cap B$ is $p_A*p_B$.

So for example the probability for $|A\cap B|=0$ is $(p_A*p_B)^0*(1-p_A*p_B)^n$. In other words: zero elements in $A\cap B$ and $n$ elements not in it.

As far as i've understood the exected value, I should simply sum up the probabilities for the cardinalities of $A\cap B$ times the actual cardinality from $0,1,...,n$.

Like this:
$E[|A\cap B|]= (p_A*p_B)^0*(1-p_A*p_B)^n*0 + (p_A*p_B)^1*(1-p_A*p_B)^{n-1}*1+\ldots + (p_A*p_B)^n*(1-p_A*p_B)^0*n= \sum_{i=0}^{n} (p_A*p_B)^i*(1-p_A*p_B)^{n-i}*i$

---

## sample solution

But the sample solution is simply:

$P(i\in A\cup B)=p_A+p_B-p_A*p_B \Rightarrow E[|A\cup B|]=n*(p_A+p_B - p_A*p_B)$

---

## why am I asking?

I don't really get their "shortcut"-approach and am wondering what's the problem with my approach (of using the basic expected value formula), since it seems that I'll receive a different result.

Regards, and thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Sample solution:**

This is based on indicator variables. Let

$$I_i = \begin{cases}
1 & \text{if $i\in A\cup B$} \\
0 & \text{if $i\notin A\cup B$.} \\
\end{cases}$$

So we have $\vert A\cup B\vert = I_1 + \cdots + I_n$, and therefore,

\begin{align}
E(\vert A\cup B\vert) &= E\left( \sum_{i=1}^n I_i \right) \\
&= \sum_{i=1}^n E(I_i) \\
&= \sum_{i=1}^n P(i\in A\cup B) \\
&= nP(1\in A\cup B) \\
&= n(1-(1-p_A)(1-p_B)) \\
&= n(p_A+p_B-p_Ap_B).
\end{align}

**Your solution:**

The sum should be

\begin{align}
E(\vert A\vert) &= \binom{n}{0}p_A^0(1-p_A)^n\cdot 0 + \binom{n}{1}p_A^1(1-p_A)^{n-1}\cdot 1 + \cdots + \binom{n}{n}p_A^n(1-p_A)^0\cdot n \\
&= \sum_{i=0}^n \binom{n}{i}p_A^i(1-p_A)^{n-i}\cdot i \\
&= np_A \qquad\text{since this sum is the expectation of a $Bin(n,p_A)$ r.v.}
\end{align}

Similarly, $E(\vert B\vert) = np_B\;$ and $\;E(\vert A\cap B\vert) = np_Ap_B$. So you get the same answer.